# Embedded Switch Case statements

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

So I am trying to test my program to see if it will add up the spending occurrence I add to it.

So I am using option 2, to add two expense occurrences, to test if that total up. Then I go to option 5 (Expense Options), then case 2 (list total expenses), and this is when it resets and breaks back to original Joption screen

```
package homebudget;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
* @author Derek
*/
public class HomeBudget 
{
//Features to add:
//Reminder 2 days before an auto deduction




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // TODO code application logic here

List<Bills> deductions = new ArrayList();
String billName, deductDate, resp;
double amount, totalAmount;
int cmd, year, month, date;
totalAmount = 0;

List<Spending> expenses = new ArrayList();
String type;

List<Income> deposits = new ArrayList();
String incomeType;

String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the budget file, none if no file");
    if (fname.compareTo("none") !=0)
    {
        FileInputStream ist = new FileInputStream(fname);
        ObjectInputStream ifile = new ObjectInputStream(ist);
        deductions = (ArrayList<Bills>) ifile.readObject();

    }
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a command from: \n" 
                + "\t1:Add a new deduction\n"  //think its done
                + "\t2:Add a new expense\n"  
                + "\t3:Add a deposit\n"  
                + "\t4:Deduction options\n"  
                + "\t5:Expense Options\n"
                + "\t6:Total balances in bank\n"
                + "\t7:quit");
        cmd = Integer.parseInt(resp);
        switch(cmd)
        {
            case 1:

            billName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the bill:");
            deductDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the deduct date:");
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the deduct amount");
            amount = Double.parseDouble(resp);

            Bills d = new Bills(billName, deductDate, amount);
            deductions.add(d);
            break;

            case 2:
            //Give the option to add new spending occurence.
            //Give option to choose from array of spending types.

            type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the type of the expense:"); 

            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of the expense:");   
            amount = Double.parseDouble(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year of the expense:");
            year = Integer.parseInt(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month of the expense:");
            month =  Integer.parseInt(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date of the expense:");
            date =  Integer.parseInt(resp);
            Spending s = new Spending(amount, type, year, month, date);
            expenses.add(s);

            break;

            //Income reporting    
            case 3:

            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the type of deposit:"); 
            incomeType = resp;
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of the deposit:");   
            amount = Double.parseDouble(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year of the deposit:");
            year = Integer.parseInt(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month of the deposit:");
            month =  Integer.parseInt(resp);
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date of the deposit:");
            date =  Integer.parseInt(resp);        
            Income i = new Income(amount, incomeType, year, month, date);

            break;

            case 4:

            //deduction options

            break;

            case 5:

            //expense options
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a command from: \n" 
                + "\t1: List all expenses in a month\n"  //done
                + "\t2: List the total spent on an expense for the month\n"  
                + "\t3: List all expenses in a year\n"  
                + "\t4: List all expenses by type in a year\n"
                + "\t5:  \n"
                + "\t6:  \n"
                + "\t7:quit");
                switch(cmd){

                    case 1:


                        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What year of expenses would you like to see?:"); 
                        year = Integer.parseInt(resp);
                        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What month of expenses would you like to see?:"); 
                        month =  Integer.parseInt(resp);

                        boolean found = false;

                        Iterator<Spending> spendIter = expenses.iterator();

                        while(!found && spendIter.hasNext())
                        {
                         s = spendIter.next();
                         if(s.getYear() == year && s.getMonth() == month)
                        {
                       //How to print out an element of this Array List?
                       System.out.println("Here is the expense list for the month number " + month + ": \n") ;
                       System.out.println("Expense Type: " + s.getType() + "Amount" + s.getAmount() + "Date" + s.getDay());


                                found = true;

                        }
                         else  
                         {
                            System.out.println("There are no expenses entered for this month.");
                            }

                        }  
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        //How to list total spending on an expense per month.
                        type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the type of the expense:"); 
                        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month of the expense:");
                        month = Integer.parseInt(resp);
                        found = false;

                        spendIter = expenses.iterator();
                        double totalSpent = 0;
                        while(spendIter.hasNext())
                        {
                         s = spendIter.next();
                         if(s.getType() == type && s.getMonth() == month)
                        {

                         totalSpent = totalSpent + s.getAmount();
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total money spent on " + type + ": $" 
                                + totalSpent);
                        }
                break;





    }


}

}
}
```

Comment: So I am using option 2, to add two expense occurrences, to test if that total up.

Then I go to option 5 (Expense Options), then case 2 (list total expenses), and this is when it resets and breaks back to original Joption screen

Comment: Instead of commenting on it, you should edit your post to add additional information.

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggested refactoring the code. Right now you have a `while` inside of a `switch` inside of another `switch` inside of another `while`. If you pull some of that functionality out into separate methods, it will be much easier to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner switch, you're still trying to switch on `cmd`, which is what the outer switch is switching on. So right before the second switch you should do something like:

```
int cmd2 = Integer.parseInt(resp);
```

and then:

```
switch (cmd2) {
```

I think you're missing a `break` somewhere too, but that's not the major problem.

Comment: That worked!  At least I got farther, as now I encountered another error.  Never would have caught that issue, and learned something new thanks!

Comment: But it is now not adding the expenses.  Gonna have to do homework on this.

Comment: Glad to help! If you have more major trouble, you can always post another question. Also if my answer solved your problem, you can accept it as the solution :)